# The red circle is in the upper left corner before the start <animateMotion>

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

My question is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59293886/7394871)
The red circle is in the upper left corner before the start animateMotion animation.
Below is a sample code.

To start the animation, click anywhere on the canvas.

```html
<div id="pathContainer4">
   <svg id="svg1" height="160" width="360">
  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
    <path stroke-dasharray="3" id="motionpath2"
  d="M 10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" />
  </g>
      <circle class="circle2" r=8 fill=red ;z-index=55>
              
        <animateMotion
    dur="2s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    begin="svg1.click">
                 <mpath href="#motionpath2" />
             </animateMotion>
         </circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I tried to hide the red circle outside the canvas by moving left `cx="-18"`
But it did not help.  The red circle began to move above the path.

```html
<div id="pathContainer4">
   <svg id="svg1" height="160" width="360">
  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
    <path stroke-dasharray="3" id="motionpath2"
  d="M 10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" />
  </g>
      <circle class="circle2" cx="-18" r=8 fill=red ;z-index=55>
              
        <animateMotion
    dur="2s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    begin="svg1.click">
                 <mpath href="#motionpath2" />
             </animateMotion>
         </circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

How to make the circle disappear from the upper left corner of the SVG canvas before the animation starts?
Any solutions in these tags will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this (using '[set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/set)'):

```html
<div id="pathContainer4">
  <svg id="svg1" height="160" width="360">
    <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
      <path
        stroke-dasharray="3"
        id="motionpath2"
        d="M 10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80"
      />
    </g>
    <circle class="circle2" r="8" fill="red" visibility="hidden">
      <set
        attributeType="XML"
        attributeName="visibility"
        to="visible"
        begin="svg1.click"
      />
      <animateMotion dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="svg1.click">
        <mpath href="#motionpath2" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Or** you could use jQuery to achieve a similar effect (ensure you apply the id="red-circle" to your circle element):

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      const circle = $("#red-circle");
      circle.hide();

      $("#svg1").click(function() {
        circle.show();
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `<set>` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/SVG/Element/set)) like this:

```
<circle class="circle2" r=8 fill=red visibility="hidden">
    <set attributeType="XML" attributeName="visibility" to="visible" begin="svg1.click" />
    <animateMotion
          dur="2s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          begin="svg1.click">
                 <mpath href="#motionpath2" />
             </animateMotion>
</circle>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some Javascript

```js
document.getElementById("circle2").style.display = "none";

function hideSVG() {
      document.getElementById("circle2").style.display = "block";  
}
```

```html
 <div id="pathContainer4">
<svg id="svg1" height="160" width="360" onclick="hideSVG()">
  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
    <path stroke-dasharray="3" id="motionpath2"
  d="M 10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" />
  </g>
      <circle id="circle2" r="8" fill="red" z-index="55" >
              
        <animateMotion
    dur="2s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    begin="svg1.click">
                 <mpath href="#motionpath2" />
             </animateMotion>
         </circle>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution, removing the begin onclick attribute, maybe that is not result you wish to achieve? if not then you would most likely need to use javascript :

```html
<div id="pathContainer4">
    <svg id="svg1" height="160" width="360">
    <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
    <path stroke-dasharray="3" id="motionpath2"
    d="M 10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" />
    </g>
    <circle class="circle2" r=8 fill=red ;z-index=55>          
    <animateMotion
    dur="2s"
    repeatCount="indefinite">
    <mpath href="#motionpath2" />
    </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: `In SVG` there is no` z-index` Animation should run and not be in motion as you

Comment: I copied his code and quickly modified it, did not note the z-index!

Answer (score 1):

### Example with 3 ball motion control buttons

Hiding the ball before starting the animation is achieved using `transform="translate(0 10)"`

```html
<div>
    <button onclick="forward.beginElement()">forward</button>
    <button onclick="middle.beginElement()">Middle</button>
    <button onclick="back.beginElement()">Back</button>
</div> 
<div id="pathContainer4">
   <svg id="svg1" height="160" width="360">
  <g  transform="translate(0 -10)"  stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
    <path fill="none" stroke-dasharray="3" id="motionpath2"
  d="M 10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" />

      <circle class="circle2" r="8" fill="red">
        
  <animateMotion
    id="forward"
    dur="2s"
    begin="indefinite"
    repeatCount="1"
    keyPoints="0;1"
    keyTimes="0;1"
       calcMode="linear"  >
   <mpath href="#motionpath2" />
  </animateMotion> 
  <animateMotion
     id="middle"
     dur="2s"
     begin="indefinite"
     repeatCount="1"
     keyPoints="0.5;1"
     keyTimes="0;1"
     calcMode="linear" >
   <mpath href="#motionpath2" />
     </animateMotion> 
     <animateMotion
     id="back"
     dur="2s"
     begin="indefinite"
     repeatCount="1"
     keyPoints="1;0"
     keyTimes="0;1"
     calcMode="linear" >
   <mpath href="#motionpath2" />
     </animateMotion> 
         </circle> 
 </g>   
</svg>
```